# Build shared library, but undefined references to functions?

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, shared-libraries, visibility

I have a basic shared library I am building for practice, and all it defines is the function placeholder in the form of

```
int placeholder() { return 1; }
```

I am building it like so with libtool in a makefile for ease (relevant portions):

```
libfootest: $(OBJECTS)
    libtool --mode=link $(CC) -g -O -o libfootest.la $(OBJECTS)\
          -rpath /usr/lib

libfootest.o: $(SRCDIR)/$(SOURCES)
    libtool --mode=compile $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/$(SOURCES)

install: libfootest
    libtool --mode=install cp libfootest.la /usr/lib/libfootest.la
```

Now I can verify that a) It is installed with the appropriate `.so.*` and `.la`, b) `nm` has the symbol `placeholder` defined in the individual libtool object (libfootest.o before linking), I believe that is all I needed.

I then now am creating a program for test purposes,

```
#include "../includes/libfootest.h" //public prototypes are here
int main() {
  int test = placeholder();
  return 0;
}
```

And of link it like `-lfootest` and it is found, although unfortunately I get an undefined reference error to placeholder!

```
/tmp/cc92NtSa.o: In function `main':
prototypes.cxx:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `placeholder()'
```

Can you spot what I had done wrong in this, or is there some sort of export I have to perform for the library to work? I have seen some apis use DLLEXPORT or similar before their function declarations, I am unsure of what they do.

Comment: What is your `readelf -Wa libfootest.so|grep placeholder` output?

Comment: @Developer: Unfortunately there are no results for the function name in it and the full output seems to not give many clues. There has to be some "visibility" feature somewhere to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

The `prototypes.cxx` was compiled in `C++` mode, which caused the reference to `placeholder()` to acquire `C++` name linkage (and get [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).

If you intend `placeholder()` to be callable from both `C` and `C++`, you must add `extern "C"` linkage to its prototype when building in `C++` mode:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int placeholder();
```

If you intend `placeholder()` to only be usable from `C++`, then build the library with `CXX` instead of `CC`.